# Docker-compose produces error: DETAIL: Password does not match for user "". db_1 | Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all all md5"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, psql, flyway

Removing volumes with
docker prune does not help,
nor removing data folder.
Basically tried removing everything that contains data from my initial compose.

Tried changing user and password in psql. Didnt help.

here is my docker YAML file:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6.10
    ports:
    - 5432:5432
    tty: true
    environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=mydb
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    volumes:
    - ./db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data


  migrate:
    image: boxfuse/flyway
    depends_on:
    - db
    volumes:
    - ./common/migrations:/flyway/sql:rw

    environment:
    - FLYWAY_USER=flyway
    - FLYWAY_PASSWORD=flyway
    - FLYWAY_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/my_web_app
    - FLYWAY_CONNECT_RETRIES=180

networks:
  default:
    name: my_web_app_local
```

Error is reproduced every time. Please help.

Comment: which container produces the error? the postgres container?

Comment: That is what I presume. I am running postgres and npm start when this error is produced.